# What does そうなろう mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I was watching this anime events clip -> https://youtu.be/5y15wDpcwuI?t=6m12s

and could not understand this particular part.

at 6:12 I think the seiyuu said

> **そうなろう**と思えば、
> この世界はどこまでも残酷になれるのだということ

I could not find this word in the online dictionary, so maybe I heard something wrong or is it possible that it simply mean "that".

---

At 6:23 I could not understand clearly what the other seiyuu said?

I believe it is

> 遠い昔に書かれたあるXXX
>
> XXX節がある

Comment: You heard her right, except for missing the final を: "そうなろうと思えば、 この世界はどこまでも残酷になれるのだということ**を**。"

Comment: @goldbrick Is it possible for you to tell me what does this **を** help with this sentence? Can it be that it indicated that the story is not finish yet?

Comment: I would, but I think it'd be better if you posted a new question for that.

Answer (score 5):

そうなろう is composed of:

- そう: "so", "that"
- なろう: the volitional form of なる ("to become")

そうなろうと思う literally means "(someone) thinks they want to become so".

And this そう refers to something said after it — 残酷になる.

> そうなろうと思えば、この世界はどこまでも残酷になれる
>   If this world wishes (to be cruel), this world can be infinitely cruel.

Yes this is an example of personification.

Answer (score 0):

> it simply mean "that"

No. そうなろうと思えば means "if (it) imagines(/wishes) (it) could be."

> 遠い昔に書かれたあるXXX

It's very hard to hear the word, but it seems she is saying「絵本に」.

> XXX節がある

こんな１節がある

Answer (score 0):

そうなろう is そう　+　なる.

The verb なる means "to become" and it is in "volitional" form here.  It's a little hard to translate literally, I think, but "そうなろうと思えば" here is like "If you think things might get like that..."

As for the second part, I can't say with 100% certainty that I'm right here, but it sounds to me like

"遠い昔に書かれた絵本こんな一節（/一説）がある"